# Stuck in Bandit level 0. (overthewire.org)

Tags: command-line, ssh, powershell, putty, administrator

While it's very easy to connect using `putty` from this machine, a Windows Surface 3, I seem to be stuck when using the console:

https://www.reddit.com/r/securityCTF/comments/6phnaw/stuck_in_bandit_level_0_overthewireorg/

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20200329143756
Username: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\thufir
RunAs User: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\thufir
Configuration Name: 
Machine: DESKTOP-9AKB65V (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 10364
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.628
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.628
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.628
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\thufir\Documents\PowerShell_transcript.DESKTOP-9AKB65V.+hfqfpT1.20200329143756.txt
PS C:\Users\thufir> ssh bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org 2220
bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org's password:
bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org: Permission denied (publickey,password).
PS C:\Users\thufir> stop-transcript
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20200329143829
**********************
```

Not sure how many ways I can type "bandit0" for a password....

Can I perhaps pass that as an argument through a configuration file?  Could be user error (me), could be that the service is overloaded or down for other reasons (but then why ask for the password), or could be, maybe, some oddity with this computer(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` is not `telnet` with its general syntax of `telnet server port`. I believe even in Windows the basic usage of `ssh` is like:

```
ssh [-p port] [user@]server [command]
```

You did `ssh bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org 2220`. You connected to the default port (22) and `2220` was the command.

It so happens there is a server on port 22, but this is not the server that accepts the credentials you know.

The command `2220` was never invoked because you failed to authenticate in the first place. Instead of `2220` it could have been anything, it wouldn't be invoked either.

You want to connect like this:

```
ssh -p 2220 bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org
```